# Wrong product code in API response

Tags: api, openfda

We are using below API to get data for product code "CAN" from 1st may 23 to 30th may 23:

[https://api.fda.gov/device/event.json?api_key=T1Hc46PBzj4XxShHdLhmdfilfr9Xpsd1DmpZo0or&search=date_received:[20230501+TO+20230530]AND+device.device_report_product_code.exact:%22CAN%22&limit=1000](https://api.fda.gov/device/event.json?api_key=T1Hc46PBzj4XxShHdLhmdfilfr9Xpsd1DmpZo0or&search=date_received:%5B20230501+TO+20230530%5DAND+device.device_report_product_code.exact:%22CAN%22&limit=1000)

My question is since we need response related to product code "CAN" only why it is giving other product codes in response like "LPO" in this case.

Answer (score 0):

This is because some device event reports contain *multiple* devices, which may include both codes. For example, report number 2518435-2023-00011 contains two devices, one of which is CAN (triggers a search hit), but the other one is LPO.

Returned results always include complete device event report records in output, so you will see both devices.